# How to filter one dataframe's columns with another dataframe's MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How should I take a set of columns of one dataframe that take values in another set of columns of a different dataframe?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is like the following:

```
df.loc[  df[['c1','c2']].isin(df2.index),  :  ] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But this code does not work. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make sure you are comparing one index with another:

```
df.loc[df.set_index(['c1','c2']).index.isin(df2.index), :] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This will only work if there are guaranteed to be 5 rows filtered.

Comment: is there a general way to do this?

Comment: This is pretty general. I'm not sure how it can be made "more general".